# как обновить размер жестокого диска win xp в virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, hdd

При установке win xp в virtualbox был выбран маленький размер жесткого диска - 10гб, со временем размер пришлось увеличить до 30 гб. Гостевая система не видит что  диск стал большего размера. как win xp указать что диск увеличился?

Comment: надо расширить диск каким-нибудь PM, например https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html, установите его в VM и расширьте

Comment: Грузишь `Gparted Live` и там всё будет видно.